# Can I create an app with swift to controle a go pro camera from the phone?

Tags: ios, entity-framework, api, ip, wifi

It is posible to create an app with swift that can make the same that "capture" do?

Capture is the app that use go pro for connect the GoPro cameras to the phone. And see on real time the media on the device.

For this I know I have to get the wifi of the phone by the code because this cameras are conected by wifi.

Is swift capable to do that or do I need any framework?

If someone has any example woul be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow 3d party developers to develop apps for product they release their API to use. So if a device provide an API you can develop an app for it.  As i searched API for go cameras i saw this website [go pro latest api](https://developer.gopro.com/info) . So i think yes you can develop your own application to use with go pro cameras

Comment: GoPro shut down their SDK: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=16189633

Comment: And it has been restarted - https://github.com/gopro/OpenGoPro